# Should I used 'ui' or 'ui.boostrap' when including angular-ui and why does angular-ui have a build sub directory?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/). According to the readme under `angular-ui/build/README.md`

> The repository comes with the modules pre-built and compressed into
>   the `build/` directory.

Usage is documented as:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui']);
```

and

> You do not need to build the project to use it - see above [...]

In order to start using angular-ui, I changed the declaration of my angular-js module to include 'ui'

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngRoute',
    'ui'
]);
```

However the [UI Bootstrap documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) states installation is achieved with:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

**Question #1:** What's the difference between using only `ui` and `ui.bootstrap`?

I then included the following js file manually into my .html file (note the build directory in the path as this relates to question 3):

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.js"></script>
```

However all other angular components are included automatically into my .html file as part of the build process:

**Question #2**: How do I use angular-ui such that it too is added as part of the build process?

**Question #3**: Why does angular-ui have .js files in a build sub-directory while other angular components do not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer # 1:** The difference is that Angular-ui is a combination of several packages of the angular-ui project specificly all (or almost all) the UI-Utils and UI-Modules, and the UI-Bootstrap is another part of the project that includes several bootstrap components writen in angular way and is not included in the Angular-UI Bundle pack ... [here for more info and see all the different packages of the project Angular UI github](https://angular-ui.github.io/)

**Answer # 2** As already you did just including the 'ui' dependency into the dependecys array of your main module, howerver it will not include the ui-bootstrap as i mention above

**Answer # 3** Those files are as you can see in the link of the main proyect of angular-ui are the modules and utils as separate components so you can delete them from your project and only include the distriburion files or you can use them separetly

Comment: Was 'here for more info' in Answer #1 supposed to be hyper-linked?  Regarding Answer #2, how can I include ui-bootstrap with angular-ui?  Maybe it' my lack of knowledge, but I don't understand Answer #3.

Comment: The link was at the end, fixed to avoid confusion on the link you can get into the ui-bootstrap section and download the components and as far as i know theres is no bundle of angular-ui with ui-bootstrap included you have to download them separetly

Comment: as for the answer 3 the js are the separated components no need for them if youre going to use the full angular-ui bundle